# how to post (http-post) content of pdf using ruby?

Tags: ruby, pdf, file-io, http-post, curb

I am trying to post (raw) content of a PDF in ruby using the following block

```
require 'pdf/reader'
require 'curb'

reader = PDF::Reader.new('folder/file.pdf')
raw_string = ''
reader.pages.each do |page|
  raw_string = raw_string + page.raw_content.to_s
end
c = Curl::Easy.new('http://0.0.0.0:4567/pdf_upload')
c.http_post(Curl::PostField.content('param1', 'value1'),Curl::PostField.content('param2', 'value2'), c.http_post(Curl::PostField.content('body', raw_string)))
```

Inside the API implementation `params[:body]` seems to be empty all the time (though        `puts raw_string` confirms that the variable has all the values.

Also, is there a better way to post pdf content?

Comment: If you suspect the problem is with the server actually receiving the data, because it appears that the posting side is correct, then we need to see a minimal example of that side of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding how you're building `raw_string`...

Instead of:

```
reader.pages.each do |page|
  raw_string = raw_string + page.raw_content.to_s
end
```

You should be able to do something like one of these:

```
raw_string = reader.pages.map(&:raw_content).join
raw_string = reader.pages.map{ |p| p.raw_content.to_s }.join
```

I'd also recommend you write your last line spread across several lines, for clarity and readability:

```
c.http_post(
  Curl::PostField.content('param1', 'value1'),
  Curl::PostField.content('param2', 'value2'), 
  c.http_post(Curl::PostField.content('body', raw_string))
)
```

Comment: Actually, if he sends the raw file, there is no real need even use `PDF::Reader`... he should simply send the file's binary contents...